# Surround dynamic img tag in an anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems with anchor and image tags. My image tags are sitting inside (what is essentially) a div tag each, the div tags have constant height and width values. The image tags are given a constant height value, so their width can be calculated based on their aspect ratio and the images do not become distorted when they're resized to fit inside the div.

I want to have an anchor tag surrounding each image for two reasons. (1.) So the images can act as links, but also (2.) so that when the user hovers over the image, I can display an overlay on top of the image.

Putting the image tag inside an anchor tag solves the problem of the link, but as for the second problem, I'm stumped. I need the anchor tag to dynamically size and position itself over its respective image tag. Ideally I'd like to avoid using JavaScript to solve the problem and just stick to CSS (if possible). I have no objection to adding a little extra markup if needs be.

Relevant HTML:

```
<listitem>

    <a href="#"><img src="../images/image1.jpg"/></a>

</listitem>

<!--More listitems with different sized images go here-->
```

And the CSS:

```
#pictureListContainer listitem {

    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: block;
    height: 257px;
    width: 636px;
}

#pictureListContainer listitem img {

    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 203px !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 21px 296px 21px auto;

    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Update: I should maybe make it clear that I would like the overlay to have the same dimensions as the image, so that it only overlays the image.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a custom `listitem` tag instead of the actual list item tag (`li`)?

Comment: Not really, apart from I'd rather not deal with `ul`s. To be honest, it hadn't really crossed my mind. :)

Comment: If there is no reason, you shouldn't be using such tags. Instead, use a `span` or a `div`. Remember that unknown tags in most browsers are treated as inline elements.

Comment: Good point. It's been several months since I wrote any HTML or CSS, so it's taking a little while for it to come back to the front of my mind. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using only CSS and HTML: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdTJQ/)

HTML

```
<div class="listitem">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://sublantic.net/forge/demos/img/code_canyon/scale.png" alt="image" />
        <span class="overlay-text">Test</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.listitem {

    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: block;
    height: 257px;
    width: 636px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.listitem img {

    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 203px !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 21px 296px 21px auto;

    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: relative;
}

.listitem a span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.listitem a:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

---

Edit: Overlay fits to image

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdTJQ/1/)

CSS

```
.listitem {

    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: block;
    height: 257px;
    width: 636px;
}

.listitem img {
    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.listitem a {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.listitem a span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.listitem a:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vimal, but would there be a way to have the span tag have the same dimensions as the img tag? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `onClick` for the image

```
<img src="" onClick="" />
```

This will eliminate the botheration of generating functionality like overlay, etc for `a` tag and you can get both effects work simultaneously well.

Hope this helps.